# CSS div's not scaling properly with it's child to max width and when it does it wont be 100%

Tags: html, css, parent, scaling

I'm trying to make my menu always be 100% width of the html/body's width, no matter what.

I thought it was working until I lowered my screen size and noticed the child div `#menu` was scaling while the parent `#top` wasn't. When I got them both to scale with each other on smaller screens they don't want to go 100% width when menu is smaller then screen size.

This is driving me insane, tried so many different ways with float, `display inline-block`, positioning etc. But cant get both ways to scale the way I want it too.

https://jsfiddle.net/pLt418pc/

Comment: please insert the code in the question itself.

Comment: Got it to work with max-width in the #top aswell.. but now the last two div's wont scale so easily.

https://jsfiddle.net/1Larddut/

Answer (score 0):

For what you are using `float:left` ? 
Here you go. Guess i correctly understand your question
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fhy666r9/)

Comment: so,for small device use horizontal  scrolling for top menu

Comment: That was my plan when I got down to closer to 400px width but this menu is pretty big and would get scrollbars already close to 800px.. Suppose I could add the smaller menu earlier but it should still be possible to do this.

Comment: For me it's hard to understand why you don't use collapsed menu with burger icon or something like that: https://scotch.io/ on the small screens. It's your opinion. Without redisign of your menu, i guess, it's impossible.